# Determine $x$-value given 3 points on a curve (Quadratic approximation)

Tags: numerical-methods

I have 3 points ($x_0$, $y_0$), ($x_1$, $y_1$) and ($x_2$, $y_2$) that lie on a monotonically-increasing (asymptotic) curve (whose function is not known *a priori*).

The only unknown value is $x_2$, which corresponds to reaching an asymptote (in the limit sense) of $y_2$.

**My question is**: Is there a straightforward numeric way to determine $x_2$? My eventual goal is to proceed iteratively until convergence is reached.

I am familiar with numerical root-finding algorithms, of which Muller's method crossed my mind, since it relies on three *known* points to construct a parabola that interpolates the points. Apart from this, my problem is different in that I wish to know the value of $x_2$ that gives $f(x_2) = y_2$.

Any thoughts on a sound approach?

Comment: Are you sure? The curve will never reach the asymptote by definition. An explicit $x_2$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel You're absolutely right! But, for all intents and purposes, suppose we could reach an asymptote (kind of a thought experiment). Is there an existing approach?

Comment: Well you definitely can find a curve that goes through two points and reaches an asymptote $y=y_2$... Would you like this as an answer?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that's just a straight line, since the function passes through two points.

Comment: But it also has to reach an asymptote. A straight line has no asymptote.

Comment: Yes, an asymptote must be reached. My last comment was simply stating that a straight line is still monotone and concave (with constant slope)

Comment: I presume you want to find an $x_2$ such that its corresponding $y_2$ is "close enough" to the asymptote, right?

Comment: Yes. "Close enough" is sufficient, say in terms of absolute or relative approximation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple function that can be made to fit the data *exactly*.
$$y=a+\frac b{x+c}$$
$a=y_2$ to reach the asymptote. To find $b$ and $c$, rearrange the equation to be linear in them and solve:
$$(y_0-y_2)(x_0+c)=(y_1-y_2)(x_1+c)=b\tag1$$
$$c=\frac{x_0(y_2-y_0)+x_1(y_1-y_2)}{y_0-y_1}$$
where the value obtained for $c$ is back-substituted into $(1)$ to find $b$. Note that $b$ will always be negative, since the function is monotonically increasing.

Now suppose $x_2$ is to be found which makes the difference between the function value there and $y_2$ less than some constant $\varepsilon>0$. This entails solving
$$y_2-\left(y_2+\frac b{x_2+c}\right)<\varepsilon$$
This is also easy:
$$-\frac b{x_2+c}<\varepsilon$$
$$x_2>-\frac b\varepsilon-c$$

Comment: This is a nice approach! But the y that you found is a monotonically-decreasing function, rather than monotonically-increasing. Simply multiplying the numerator of the second term by $x$ will solve the problem. I guess I didn't specify that beforehand. Anyway, it's solved.

Comment: @JarrettPhillips $b$ is negative, as I said in the answer. So it is really monotonically _increasing_.

Comment: Sorry, I glossed over that part in your response. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @JarrettPhillips Now upvote and accept my answer (you do seem to be new here).

Comment: Yes, I am! And I will!